# Contradicting approaches to deriving power needed for a flywheel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

My problem involves a flywheel of moment of inertia, $I$. I would like the flywheel to start at rest and achieve a rotational velocity of $\omega$, within $t$ time. I see two approaches to the problem, but they give different answers meaning I have made a false assumption somewhere.

**The first approach is an energy approach**:

The kinetic energy of the flywheel at rotational velocity $\omega$ is $T = \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$. My reasoning is that this amount of energy needs to be achieved in $t$ seconds which implies that $P = \frac{I\omega^2}{2t}$.

**The second approach is to use torque/acceleration**.

Again, I want a rotational velocity of $\omega$ in $t$ time. This implies that I need a angular acceleration of $\alpha = \omega/t$ which further implies that I will need a torque of $\tau = \frac{I\omega}{t}$. Using the formula $P=\tau\omega$, means that the required power is $P=\frac{I\omega^2}{t}$.

Note the difference between the two approaches, namely the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$. Both approaches seem reasonable: what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Using the formula  = , means that the required [mean] power is $P=\frac {I\omega^2}t$.

This is where your mistake lies... You have previously been using $\omega$ to mean the flywheel's final velocity, but in this last step you need to multiply the torque (which really is $\frac{I\omega}t)$
by the mean angular velocity of the wheel while it is being accelerated, that is by $\omega/2$. This works because in your method the angular acceleration is constant in magnitude.

A method of calculating the power that doesn't rely on constant acceleration uses $\omega$ to mean the *instantaneous* angular velocity during acceleration, in which case the instantaneous power is
$$P=\frac{\tau\ \Delta\theta}{\Delta t}=\tau\ \omega=I\frac{d\omega}{dt}\omega=\frac d {dt}\left(\tfrac 12 I\omega^2\right).$$
What has appeared inside the round brackets is the kinetic energy formula, and we have therefore shown the equivalence between your two methods.